# manipulating global varaible in different scenarios

Tags: php

i have function which basically generates dynamic links for a dynamic menu, now what i basically want to do is i need to declare a variable outside the function then there are two parts inside the function where i want to get value and concatenate the value to the global variable after recursive calls to that function i want to use that value outside the function so see what i got! here's the code

```
<?php
                define("hostname",$this->db->hostname);
                define("username",$this->db->username);
                define("password",$this->db->password);
                define("database",$this->db->database);


                $var="";//this is the variable i want to use


                ?>
                <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
                    <li><a href="<?=base_url()?>Home" style="color: white;"><img id="navbar-home" src="<?=base_url()?>images/navbar_hover_home.png" class="img-responsive"></a></li>
                    <?php

                    function display_children($parent, $level) {
                        $conn=mysqli_connect(hostname,username,password,database) or die ("not connected");
                        $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT a.id, a.title , a.page_id , a.custom_link ,a.priority, Deriv1.Count FROM `menu` a  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT parent, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM `menu` GROUP BY parent ) Deriv1 ON a.id = Deriv1.parent WHERE a.parent='$parent' ORDER BY a.priority");

                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                            if ($row['Count'] > 0) {

                                $link="";
                                if($row['page_id']){
                                    $link=base_url().$row['page_id'];
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $link=$row['custom_link'];
                                }
                                $title=$row['title'];
                                if($title=="OPERAS PHYSICIAN LOG IN"){
                                    $title="OPERAS Physicians Log-In";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $title= strtoupper(str_replace('-', ' ', clean($row['title']) ));
                                }
                                echo "<script>console.log('".$title."')</script>";
                                echo "<li><a href='" . $link . "'>" .$title . "<span class=caret></span></a>";
                                echo "<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\">";

                                global $var;//this is where is want to manipulate the variable
                                $var.=$title;

                                display_children($row['id'], $level + 1);


                                echo "</ul>";
                                echo "</li>";
                                echo "<li class=\"divider\"></li>";

                            } elseif ($row['Count']==0) {
                                $link="";
                                if($row['page_id']){
                                    $link=base_url().$row['page_id'];
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $link=$row['custom_link'];
                                }
                                $title=$row['title'];
                                if($title=="OPERAS PHYSICIAN LOG IN"){
                                    $title="OPERAS Physicians Log-In";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $title= strtoupper(str_replace('-', ' ', clean($row['title']) ));
                                }



                                global $var;//this is where is want to manipulate the variable
                                $var.=$title;


                                echo "<script>console.log('".$title."')</script>";
                                echo "<li><a href='" . $link . "'>" . $title . "</a></li>";
                                echo "<li class=\"divider\"></li>";
                            } else;

                        }

                    }

                    function clean($string) {
                        return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', ' ', $string); // Removes special chars.
                    }

                    display_children(0, 1);


                    echo $var;//returns null

                    ?>
                </ul>
```

now i looked over many questions but what they are doing is using a global variable inside a function where as i want to use the global variable inside the function and after the use he same variable with updated values outside the function. any help?

Comment: Just learn how to code object oriented then get rid of globals and mixing markup + logic ... otherwise you will have to care about this messy code permanently

Comment: hmm i like the thought! can you just give me a very basic example using oop for my case? so that i may know what i am trying to learn

Comment: _very basic example using oop for my case?_ Now this is the time when YOUR research should start.... a very basic example is worth nothing.... you will need to learn OOP from the basics... there are mega tons of tutorials and examples out there

Comment: alrighty thanks i'll look into it

Comment: Beyond the OOP approach (which is better), why do you not return the value of $title from you function display_children, and call $var = display_children(...) ?  You do not use $var anywere inside the function anyway, you just assign a value to it.

Comment: actually i will need to manipulate this value on every recursive call of function just returning is not my scenario